# JsonFactory on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jwt

I am implementing a GoogleId JWT parse following this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?m=1).  I have not been able to find the com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory dependency.  Where can this be found??  I've tried several of the google-api libraries and have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether its been moved. 
But according to google-api-java-client its here now:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory.java?r=cb1c9c7991588a72fc4487170e137ae988593ae2

Seems that the blog post you referred to is importing it as above as well:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
```

Maybe its been moved and updated.
Hope that helps.